# Can QuckSync h264_qsv do 4.2.2 (p010le) encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, intel-graphics

I've run into an odd situation that I can't resolve.

When I retrieve the encoder characteristics of the ffmpeg build I'm using, it shows that the h264_qsv codec supports three pixel formats:

'''
I:\Downloads>ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_qsv
Encoder h264_qsv [H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration)]:
General capabilities: delay hybrid
Threading capabilities: none
Supported hardware devices: qsv qsv qsv
Supported pixel formats: nv12 p010le qsv
h264_qsv encoder AVOptions:
-async_depth               E..V....... Maximum processing parallelism (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 4)
-avbr_accuracy             E..V....... Accuracy of the AVBR ratecontrol (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
-avbr_convergence          E..V....... Convergence of the AVBR ratecontrol (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
-preset                    E..V....... (from 1 to 7) (default medium)
veryfast        7            E..V.......

[and so on.]

'''

But when I copy the pixel format "p010le" and paste it into my batch file that I used for trans-coding, and which works if I let it use the default nv12 format, I get an error:

'''
I:\Capture>ffmpeg -hide_banner -err_detect ignore_err -loglevel info -stats -benchmark  -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=qsv -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -vsync vfr -ec deblock  -ss 00:01:32.432 -to 00:10:53.064  -i "Little Cheeser 1936 raw.avi"    -strict normal -fflags +igndts+genpts -c:a aac -q:a 0.9 -ac 1 -af dynaudnorm -g 60  -async_depth 128   -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=128,format=p010le,vpp_qsv=cw=948:ch=720:cx=0:cy=0"  -q:v 28  -c:v h264_qsv  -preset veryslow    -rdo 1 -extbrc 1 -look_ahead_depth 100 -look_ahead_downsampling auto -avbr_accuracy 500   -mbd rd -refs 4 -me_range 1024 -trellis 2 -idct auto -subq 8 -adaptive_i 1 -adaptive_b 1 -flags +aic+mv4+qpel+ilme+loop  -movflags +faststart "Little Cheeser 1936.mp4"
Input #0, avi, from 'Little Cheeser 1936 raw.avi':
Duration: 00:11:06.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4157 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3943 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 120 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
File 'Little Cheeser 1936.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_hwupload_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
bench: maxrss=60096kB
Conversion failed!
'''
(I've inserted a blank line before the error to make it easier to find.)

I have tried simplifying the video filter stream to just "format=p0101le", but I get the same failure.  I've also tried doing it separately with -pix_fmt p010le" in the command outside of the video filter, and also get an error.  I've tried stripping the command down to the basics, but that also does not fix the error.

I don't understand why ffmpeg would extract information about the codec and say that it supports p0101le if it doesn't.  Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats) `P010` applies "Planar, 4:2:0, 10-bit" (not  4:2:2 as written in the title). According to the [following page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync), "Encode a 1080p p010le raw yuv input as HEVC main10 profile (supported since Kaby Lake platform)". (Kaby Lake applies Intel Core Gen 7). I don't know since which version FFmpeg support it. Try moving `format=p010le` before `hwupload`.

Comment: I've tried moving pix_fmt p010le before the video filter, after the video filter, before h264_qsv, after h264_qsb; and I've tried format=p0101le before and after the hwupload (though I know from past experience and examples I've seen that putting format=nv12 after hwupload works) and I've tried just -vf "format=p010le" with nothing else in the filter. No matter what I do there is always an error.   I should also mention that the input file is AVC, Codec ID H264, Chroma subsampling 4.2.2 acording to MediaInfo.  ffmpeg says it's High 4:2:2 and yuv422p.

Comment: I see you are using `-c:v h264_qsv`, try `-c:v hevc_qsv` (H.265) - `h264_qsv` supports only nv12. Try software decoding and hardware encoding: Add `-c:v h264` before the `-i`. Then `"format=p010le,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=128"`. Try with and without `-pix_fmt p010le`. Execute `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_qsv` and look for additional relevant arguments. My CPU is too old for trying it...

Comment: I've never been able to get encoding with hevc_qsv to work at all.  That is a separate problem I might post here as a separate topic.  The main issue is that ffmpeg says h264_qsv supports p010le, and it apparently doesn't. I can't tell if the fault is in something ffmpeg is doing, or if the fault is in the Intel software, but there are reasons for my wanting the output in this case to be h264.  Regarding using h264_qsv for decoding input, that's also a different problem: I do use it regularly for some input files, but the h264_qsv I have doesn't always 'like' this particular source.

Comment: After quite some time using QSV, I've learned more about it and the VPP_QSV filter.  The big problem here is that different generations of Intel processors have different capabilities: just because Intel says QSV will do something does not mean that the specific CPU/GPU you have will do it.  There is a resource that will tell you what your processor will actually do, but it's not to be found anywhere on the Intel web site, it is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video